# macOS - Transition between view controllers like iOS, dont open separate window

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

Im building an app in swift for macOS, and I have a button on my initial view controller that I want to display a different view controller. I ctrl dragged from that button to the new view controller, and all of the segue options display the new view controller as a new window, rather that replacing the initial view. How can I make this button transition view controllers similar to how it works in iOS apps?

Answer (score 0):

You can first make your segue to the 2nd view controller and then create an IBAction from your button where you call

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {})
```

within it. By doing this your initial view controller will no longer exist.

**More detailed:**

1. Segue from your button to the second view controller (ctrl drag)
2. Make an IB**Action** by ctrl drag from your button to the view controllers code
3. Put this into your IBAction:

   self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {})

Now it should look something like this:

```
@IBAction func dismissView(_ sender: Any) {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {})
}
```

By clicking on your button your application go to the next view controller and the initial view controller will be dismissed.